# Method not found: 'Void System.Security.Claims.ClaimIdentity..ctor(System.Security.Claims.ClaimIdentity)'

Tags: .net, frameworks, missingmethodexception

One of our client is facing the error as mentioned in title, we confirmed that .NET Framework 4.5.2 was installed, we did uninstall it and again installed. The machine is Windows Server 2012 R2
Further analysis on this issue found that System.Security.Claims namespace exists in mscorlib.dll which is main assembly for .NET framework.

Not sure how to resolve it as it is been long since they are facing this issue.
The Web application on which this error is coming is on .NET Framework 4.5.2 and it is an ASP.NET web form application which uses form authentication.
The login page displays but when giving username/password then this error is coming.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Anurag

Answer (score 3):

The  `ClaimsIdentity` type has been available since .NET  4.5 (see "Version Information" [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx)); however, *that constructor* has only been available since .NET 4.6 (see "Version Information" [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn956561(v=vs.110).aspx)). So: either  use a different constructor, or  take  a dependency on  .NET 4.6 - your current .NET 4.5.2 is not sufficient.

Comment: Hey Marc, Thanks for this input,

Comment: Hey Marc, Thanks for this input, I am thinking that earlier in Windows 2012 Server R2 the client had 4.6.1 installed but they uninstalled it as this issue was coming and installed 4.52 as we thought our application supports 4.5.2 version. Also we are not explicitly calling the constructor of ClaimsIdentity, perhaps it is being called internally.

Comment: Hi Marc, Appreciate if you have some more light on this case. We are struggling with this but have no idea. As I said earlier we are not explicitly using constructor but using form authentication

Comment: @anuragsji I'd need a stack trace to comment more

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in one of your comments to Marc's answer, this error can be caused if a rollback from .NET 4.6.1 to .NET 4.5.2 is not completed perfectly. I experienced this error message after rolling back from .NET 4.6.1 on Windows Server 2012 R2 by uninstalling the Windows Update KB3102467.  When I reinstalled the Windows Update the error was resolved.

You could try repeating the steps described [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/02/10/on-net-framework-4-6-1-and-exchange-compatibility/) or [here](http://www.expta.com/2016/02/how-to-uninstall-net-framework-461.html) to attempt restore .NET 4.5.2 more perfectly.  You could also attempt to use the .NET Framework repair or cleanup tools mentioned in [this post](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/uninstall-microsoft-net-framework-with-aaron-stebner-cleanup-tool/).

I performed all of those steps and still experienced this error, so I decided it was simpler and faster to upgrade back to .NET 4.6.1.